# In Heroku Dataclips, how to hide the Query

Tags: heroku

Is there a way to hide the Query shown at the top of the DataClip on Heroku?
I would like to give access to view the data but not the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you want, but you don't get the query included when you just download the data as .csv

Comment: Adding any of the currently three extensions will just download the file (`.csv`, `.xls`, `.json`) and, you are correct, the file does not contain the query. But if the URL is given to someone and they remove the `.csv` or other extension, then they get the page with the Query on it.